# Cuenta Atras en Android Studio

Tags: android

quería crear una cuenta atrás para un juego, como por ejemplo que se recarguen las vidas después de un tiempo. Sé cómo hacer una cuenta atrás , el problema es que no se cómo hacer que siga al salir de la aplicación (cuando se cierra completamente , incluso cuando se reinicia el celular)
Busque mucho y creo que la mejor opción sería la de comenzar un conteo cuando salga de la aplicación y al volver a entrar restar el tiempo transcurrido a la cuenta atras . Alguien me puede orientar un poco como hacer esto ? Gracias

Comment: Y si en vez de una cuenta atras, calculas un tiempo del dia y pones un trigger cuando sea ese tiempo?

Answer (score 1):

Para medir si ha transcurrido X tiempo puedes obtener la fecha/hora actual comparando con una anterior

Con los eventos `onStart()` y `onStop()` puedes detectar si la app está a primer plano o en sengundo plano.
Es donde puedes iniciar la cuenta atras "segundo a segundo" y en onStop parar el contador.

En el evento `onCreate()`, puedes obtener el valor fecha/hora guardado en `SharedPreferences` para así cuando el usuario vuelve abrir de nuevo la app, sigue el contador

Te dejo un diagrama de la vida de un activity
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]